# Is there an intuitive answer why burning is very exothermic?

Tags: bond, energy, combustion

Water and carbon dioxide are much lower in energy than hydrocarbon and oxygen. Is there an intuitive answer for this? Is this because atom arrangements that have more polar bonds tend to be lower in energy? Or there are some other reasons? Or there is no meaningful rationalization here and it is just the way it is?

Comment: Is a fire hot? Giving off heat?

Comment: There is an [article in JChemEd](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jchemed.5b00333) that blames it on the weak bonding of dioxygen.

Comment: From the time one sees a fire one intuitively realizes that wood , paper, gasoline etc. burn and when as a boy or girl scout asked to build a fire one gathered sticks to burn and stones to control the fire. Then one studies chemistry and learns about bond energies, Hess's Law, poorly shielded orbitals, and forgets that observation and perhaps even measurement is the most important aspect of chemistry. Observation, intuition, logic and measurement can be a powerful combination, HMMM wonder why rocks do not burn?

Comment: @jimchmst - coal burns just fine...

Comment: @Jon Custer my question is about why water and Carbon dioxide are much lower in energy in terms of their atomic position. My question is "Is there a reason X that leads to B, while B is equivalent to C". An answer "C (Burning is hot) leads to B (water and CO2 have lower energy)" is not what I'm asking.

Comment: @Karsten
I see that (on the first look) the paper didn't consider the polarity of a bond as a factor. For instance, it says "The bond energies in the fuel play only a minor role; for example, the total bond energy of CH4 is nearly the same as that of CO2". This is to be expected, given CO2 is more polar but also more "strained" in terms of orientation of its orbitals.

Comment: Also, some combustion reactions are less exothermic than others: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cool_flame

Comment: If we're going for pure intuition, perhaps the answer with the least amount of required underlying knowledge/assumptions (though not immediately obvious) is that combustion is kind of reverse photosynthesis, and photosynthesis consumes light. Burning organic matter is just opening a bag of stored sunshine.

Answer (score 2):

If you add up the enthalpies of formation for a bunch of hydrocarbons and oxygen and compare it the the products (carbon dioxide and water) of rearranging the original atoms into those products, you will find that the products contain much less energy than the starting materials. That energy difference is the energy released by burning the hydrocarbons in oxygen.

This is one way of restating that the reaction is exothermic.

But, if the question is why do carbon dioxide and water have such low energy compared to the hydrocarbons plus oxygen that is more complicated.

Carbon dioxide has two strong bonds between carbon and oxygen. You could argue that this is because two polarised bonds (oxygen is keener to attract electrons than carbon) is a big part of that but this is probably an oversimplification. More complex arguments get into molecular orbital theory.

In truth there isn't a *simple* theory that explains why water plus CO2 have stronger bonds (lower energy) than the hydrocarbon-oxygen  mixture. But, if you do know their enthalpies of formation, it is easy to see why they often are the end-product of combustion. You could probably, with a lot of effort, calculate the thermodynamic parameters from some *ab initio* quantum calculations but that wouldn't give a *simple* satisfactory answer either.

Comment: I agree sometime there is no simple rationalization for how things work the way they do. Now "You could argue... polarised bonds... is a big part of that but this is probably an oversimplification. More complex arguments get into molecular orbital theory" is there a specific reason why you think this is probably an oversimplification? If anything, I feel =C= is strained and would tend to increase energy of CO2.

Comment: The C=O bonds is carbon dioxide are not at all "strained" but this probably needs molecular orbital theory for a good explanation. Simple explanations involving electronegativity or the ionic character of bonds rarely capture important issues like the geometry of the bond (CO2 has pi-bonds but the C-O pi-bonds are orthogonal). O2 is a diradical: how to explain that without molecular orbital theory?

Answer (score 1):

Oxygen loves electrons, and tries to gain as much partial negative charge as it can. This leads to a huge release of energy when it forms bonds with carbon or hydrogen, both of which are less electronegative than it.

O2 -> Two bonds, both to another oxygen atom (well, technically 1, but MO theory isn't relevant here)

H2O -> Two bonds, both to a less electronegative hydrogen atom.
CO2 -> Two bonds again, though there's definitely diminishing returns with repeated bond formation with the same carbon atom.